# Crontab is not working as expected

Tags: python, cron

I created one crontab entry by which it is supposed to run the python script every one hour. Here is my crontab entry:

```
0 * * * * /usr/bin/python3.4 /home/nattubuntu1/lab/files/cdr_format_change.py
```

But it is running every 10 minutes. After a bit research, I found this crontab entry to run job every hour.
What is going wrong with this? how do I run my python script every hour? Thank you

Comment: Is that your personal cron entry that you've created with `crontab -e` or is it a line in `/etc/crontab` ?

Comment: I have created it using `crontab -e`

Comment: How do I solve this?

Comment: I would try doing something like this first and determine for sure that it is running through your cron:

Comment: `0 * * * *  touch /home/nattubuntu1/testfile.\`date  +\%H\%M\%S\` ; /usr/bin/python3.4 /home/nattubuntu1/lab/files/cdr_format_change.py
`

Comment: Every hour that should create a file with a name like `testfile.700000` before your python script is run.

Comment: I am struggling to see what is wrong with your cron entry. All looks correct.

Comment: looks good to me. Check if you have some cron entries in `/etc/crontab` or `/etc/cron.d/` or `/etc/cron.hourly` or any of the other `/etc/cron.x`

Comment: @ChrisGuest problem solved for me. thank you very much. My crontab was not working. The one that was created with root user is running. Thank you very much for your help and efforts.

Comment: Can you please try this?  0 */1 * * *

Answer (score 3):

From what I can see, nothing. However, as an aside, you can solve this problem by placing your cronjob in "cron.hourly".

This is usually located in /etc/cron.hourly/